# How to get wizard description using SWTBot?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin, swtbot

How to get the description text of an eclipse wizard using SWTBot? The `wizard.shell.gettext()` method gives the title, but I could not find any method for getting the description.I need it to verify the description and the error messages displayed on the wizard page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as a workaround , I used this code

```
public void verifyWizardMessage(String message) throws AssertionError{
    try{
       bot.text(" "+message);
    }catch(WidgetNotFoundException e){
        throw (new AssertionError("no matching message found"));
    }
}
```

here bot is a SWTBot instance available to method.The wizard messages automatically prepends a space to the description field,so I m using `" "+message`. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

In order to test our eclipse plug-ins, the team I worked with developped a custom DSL on top of SWTBot to represent wizards, dialogs and so-on. Here is a code snippet that is working well in our case (**beware that this might be eclipse version dependent**, seems OK with eclipse 3.6 and 4.2)

```
class Foo {

    /**
     * The shell of your dialog/wizard
     */
    private SWTBotShell shell;

    protected SWTBotShell getShell() {
        return shell;
    }

    protected <T extends Widget> T getTopLevelCompositeChild(final Class<T> clazz, final int index) {
        return UIThreadRunnable.syncExec(shell.display, new Result<T>() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public T run() {
                Shell widget = getShell().widget;
                if (!widget.isDisposed()) {
                    for (Control control : widget.getChildren()) {
                        if (control instanceof Composite) {
                            Composite composite = (Composite) control;
                            int counter = 0;
                            for (Control child : composite.getChildren()) {
                                if (clazz.isInstance(child)) {
                                    if (counter == index) {
                                        return (T) child;
                                    }
                                    ++counter;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Returns the wizard's description or message displayed in its title dialog
     * area.
     *
     * A wizard's description or message is stored in the very first Text widget
     * (cf. <tt>TitleAreaDialog.messageLabel</tt> initialization in
     * <tt>org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog.createTitleArea(Composite)</tt>
     * ).
     *
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        final Text text = getTopLevelCompositeChild(Text.class, 0);
        return UIThreadRunnable.syncExec(getShell().display, new Result<String>() {

            public String run() {
                if (text != null && !text.isDisposed()) {
                    return text.getText();
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of WizardNewProjectCreationPage I use:

```
bot.textWithLabel("Create Project"); // This title set by page.setTitle("Create Project");
bot.text("Description."); // this is description set by page.setDescription("Description.");
```